# How to hide/remove checkbox from p-table header

Tags: angular, checkbox, primefaces, primeng-datatable

I used primeng p-table for multiple selection grid. I have requirement to select multiple row by clicking on each row checkbox. I have to hide/remove checkbox from ptable header.

Can I get solution for this. I have tried changing css styles but couldn't able to hide checkbox in header of ptable. thanks in advance.

Comment: Below is code I have adding in html code. 

<p-dataTable> 
      <p-column [style]="{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>

Comment: Bad tagging, remove the wrong tag. Please 'know' what you use....

Comment: Wrong correction... I removed PrimeNG from the title since there is no need to add 'tags' to the title. Click the PrimeFaces tag. Read the info and check if you use that

Comment: Thanks for corrections kukeltje. I have posted for the first time so.

Comment: I have found solution for above question. Below code is solution for the same.

<p-headerColumnGroup type="header">
            <p-row>
               <p-column [style]="{'width':'38px'}"></p-column>
               <p-column *ngFor="let col of orderCol"
[sortable]="col.sortable" [header]="col.header"></p-column>
            </p-row>
        </p-headerColumnGroup>
<p-column
[style]="{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>

Comment: Answers should be in answers, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

For adding and removing elements, Angular has the *ngIf="" directive.

Edit: When scrolling through the documentation ([here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable)), i read that the column has a hidden property. Use that.

```
hidden  boolean false   Controls visiblity of the column.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried having *ngIf for <p-column> tag, i think primeng won't support that feature. I need checkbox in each row but not in p-table header.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to remove "Checkbox" from header is through styles.

Check the dom tree for **style hierarchy** and as per **your code modify below code** to suits your hierarchy. Typical hierarchy as below.

```css
th.p-selection-column .p-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
```